# Keyboard shortcuts in toolbar

Tags: wpf

I am writing a WPF application with just a few commands, so I am using a toolbar, without a menu. I would like to assign ctrl-key shortcuts to the buttons on the toolbar. Is there a simple way to do this, without having to create routed commands or ICommands just to support the shortcuts? I would prefer to do it in XAML, rather than code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that WPF doesn't provide a simple way to add a Ctrl-key to a button. I solved my problem by trapping keypresses in the code-behind, and then invoking the appropriate ICommand--the ICommand that the corresponding button's Command property is bound to. It's a bit of an ugly hack, but it works, and it seems to be the best approach under the circumstances.

Comment: Based on your comment on my answer, I'm not sure I understood your question. But I think your overkilling it. WPF CommandBindings do exactly what you need as long as the control you're using has a Command attribute. You just set the ApplicationCommand and they keyboard gesture is automatically set to it. In my example, if you do Ctrl + O, CommandBinding_Executed will get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You do need code, one event tells the command if it can be executed (no more than a few lines usually), the other what to do, so every control bound to it does the same thing. Here's a very simple example:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTests.AppCommands"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Height="16" Name="checkBoxCanExecute" Margin="8" IsChecked="true">Can execute</CheckBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="24" Padding="8,0,8,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8" Command="ApplicationCommands.New">ApplicationCommand.New</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

```
namespace WPFTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AppCommands.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AppCommands : UserControl
    {
        public AppCommands()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = (bool)checkBoxCanExecute.IsChecked;
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New executed");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: By request of RichardOD. Here's a little more info I posted in my comment:

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New">
```

This puts the keyboard gesture Ctrl + N on the button. If you were to do

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open">
```

It would put Ctrl + O. This is implicitly implemented in WPF's CommandBindings. You can even create your own command with your own gesture. And if you bind the command to a menu item, it will automatically show the gesture beside the command name without any extra efforr, just:

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
```

This would show [New Ctrl + N] in the menu item.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think it answers the question that I asked. All I want to do is put a Ctrl-Key on the button; for example, Ctrl-O to to invoke the 'Open File' button.

Comment: <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New"> This puts the keyboard gesture Ctrl + N on the button. If you were to do <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"> it would put Ctrl + O. This is implicitly implemented in WPF's CommandBindings. You can even create your own command with your own gesture. And if you bind the command to a menu item, it will automatically show the gesture beside the command name without any extra effor, just <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />. This would show [New Ctrl + N] in the menu item.

Comment: +1 Carlo, I would move your comment into the answer, as your comment is really the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and dirty way is to just add keyboard shortcut by yourself. Of course, if you change shortcut you use in Command, you must change it manually in the tool tip. But maybe we can bind the tool tip text to Command's properties to get a shortcut via binding? Anyone knows if it possible?

```
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenDllCommand}" Content="Bla-bla >
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="F6" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Open MbUnit / MINT DLL with tests" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
```